iPad Pro M4 unable to connect to monitor through USB-C dock
2024 iPad Pro M4 13". I'm unable to connect to an external display through a USB-C dock. The iPad connects fine to the USB mouse and keyboard through the dock, but does not see the display. The iPad also connects fine to the display directly through a USB-C connection, but then does not see the peripherals on the dock.
The setup works fine with Windows and Mac laptops. It's only the iPad Pro that doesn't see the display.
Here's what I've tried:

Four different dock models from Lenovo and Targus
Multiple high bandwidth/high power USB-C cables between the iPad and the dock
Multiple video connections between the dock and the external display:
HDMI, DisplayPort, and USB-C
iPadOS 17.6.1, 18.0b, 18.1b
Rebooting iPad
Power cycling display
Power cycling docks

Nothing works. I also can't find any way to debug -- is there anywhere I can look to see why the iPad doesn't see the video connection?
I filed a radar a while back but never heard anything.

Sounds like a bandwidth issue. You could try turning down the refresh rate from 120 Hz to 60 Hz: Settings > Accessibility > Motion > Limit Frame Rate: On.

Thanks! That's the first useful tip I've gotten. I just tried it and unfortunately no different--I set limit frame rate, plugged/unplugged the dock and power cycled the monitor. Anything else I might need to do to get it to take effect?

Does it work with no other peripherals connected to the dock? If not, I don't know of anything else you can do other than to try a different dock. A Thunderbolt hub might work, but that's just a guess. The Apple Support page on this subject doesn't mention connecting through a dock: https://support.apple.com/en-us/108894 . Other World Computing sells peripherals with an emphasis on Apple compatibility, so you could ask their pre-sales support whether any of their stuff can do what you want.
